# Reset default VS Code profile to defaults

Tags: visual-studio-code

Now that Visual Studio Code has [profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles), I'd like to reset my (bloated) Default profile back to "factory defaults", and define specific profiles for Erlang, C++, Java, Flutter, etc.

How do I clear out my default profile? I've looked for it [on disk](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_where-are-profiles-kept), but only custom profiles appear here.

Comment: In the profiles documentation you linked, the first "Common Question" is [Where are profiles kept?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_where-are-profiles-kept) - it appears to me that the "Default" profile is not stored as a distinct profile, but rather as the base configuration. Each profile then overrides some or all of the base configuration.

Answer (score 0):

## This is the nuclear option, so back up first

First, quit VS Code.

### Delete *ALL* Settings

Per the [documentation for User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations), your settings are stored at:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Go to the parent of the `Code` directory in the above (e.g. on Mac):

```
cd $HOME/Library/Application\ Support
```

Move the `Code` directory somewhere safe:

```
mv Code Code.backup
```

### Delete Extensions

The above won't delete the extensions. To do that:

```
code --list-extensions | xargs -n1 code --uninstall-extension
```

On Powershell, that's:

```
code --list-extensions | % { code --uninstall-extension $_ }
```

You might need to run this a few times: it doesn't take dependencies into consideration, so it didn't uninstall the Dart extension the first time.

I'm also not sure how it plays with WSL-installed extensions.

### Restart VS Code

Restart VS Code. It should be pristine.

Comment: I would advice anyone to be careful when uninstalling the extensions, as it will uninstall all of them (including ones in other profiles).

Answer (score -1):

- Run `Profiles: Switch Profile...` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), and select the default profile.
- Run `Profiles: Show Profile Contents` in the command palette.
- In the profile view that appears, click each JSON file and just delete the contents. That includes:

  - settings.json,
  - keybindings.json,
  - for the language snippet files, you can just delete the files altogether (see their paths in the breadcrumbs, or hover over their tab to get their path)